# Is a rollback necessary when insert of a single database record fails?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am not too familiar with database transactions.  I was wondering about a situation where a single record is being inserted into a database.  Is a transaction necessary.  If so, if the insert of the one record fails, is a rollback necessary?

I am asking this related to JDBC but is can be in a general database sense.

Comment: rollbacks are only when using transaction and transaction are only needed when doing multiple inserts or updates that are tied together. For more info https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: Is there a downside to enclosing a single insert/update in a transaction and attempting commit/rollback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the doc:

1. [Statement-Level Rollback](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/transact.htm#sthref615)

   > **Statement-Level Rollback**
   > If at any time during execution a SQL statement causes an error, all effects of the statement are rolled back. The effect of the rollback is as if that statement had never been run. This operation is a statement-level rollback.
2. [Statement-Level Atomicity](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/transactions.html#GUID-5A632477-AC9E-4BC7-BB06-26B64837BF90)

   > **Statement-Level Atomicity**
   > Oracle Database supports statement-level atomicity, which means that a SQL statement is an atomic unit of work and either completely succeeds or completely fails.

So, you don't need to rollback if you execute just the only insert statement and it fails.